# Android. ConstraintLayout: TextView is not constraint, margin not working

Tags: android, textview, constraints, margin, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to use constraint flow. I need to arrange the TextView one after another on the screen.
Here is my code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="[AAAAAAAA]"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="[BBBBBBBB]"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="[CCCCCCCC]"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="[DDDDDDDD]"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="[EEEEEEEE]"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="[FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF]"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
        android:id="@+id/flow1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="text1,text2,text3,text4,text5,text6"
        app:flow_horizontalBias="0"
        app:flow_horizontalGap="10dp"
        app:flow_horizontalStyle="packed"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        app:flow_verticalBias="0"
        app:flow_wrapMode="chain"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_goneMarginEnd="20dp" />


 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Everything works well except for the last TextView. Since the text is very long, some of the text goes off the screen (See the picture below). I am trying to set margin, but it doesn't work.
I added TextView in xml for clarity. I need to add them dynamically at runtime, so I can't set the width of my TextView to match_parent, because I don't know if the content will fit within the screen.
Please help me. I need a margin on the right, regardless of the length of the text in the TextView.

[image]

**Note**: TextViews can also be added dynamically. **I need add TextView at runtime.** Therefore, I cannot set the width of the TextView to match_parent in runtime, because I don’t know if the text can fit within the width of the screen or not.

Here is my code to add View programatically:

```
  private fun addViews() {
        val list = generateChipButtons()

        list.forEach { button ->
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(baseContext).inflate(R.layout.chip_view, constraintContainer, false).apply {
                id = View.generateViewId()
                this.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvChipText).text = button.text
            }
            constraintContainer.addView(view)
            flowView.addView(view)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show your Java or Kotlin code which adds TextView dynamically.

Comment: @Sniffer, see edits please

Comment: Check [this](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/java/how+to+set+view+width+programmatically+in+android)

Comment: @Sniffer, If I make the width of the TextView match_parent it will not be entirely correct. Since my text of the view can contain short text, in this case, other views can fit in the line, however, if I set a match_parent , then the other views will no longer fit.

Comment: it's up to you. You have to design your view as per your need

Answer (score 2):

Set `0dp` at width and add a contrast to set the size ratio for width. The code above is shown with `wrap_content`, with the width exceeding the text size.

```html
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="[FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF]"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please look at the note in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `match_parent` for `TextView` text6. Try below code

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="[AAAAAAAA]"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="[BBBBBBBB]"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="[CCCCCCCC]"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="[DDDDDDDD]"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="[EEEEEEEE]"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text6"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="[FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF]"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
    android:id="@+id/flow1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:padding="10dp"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="text1,text2,text3,text4,text5,text6"
    app:flow_horizontalBias="0"
    app:flow_horizontalGap="10dp"
    app:flow_horizontalStyle="packed"
    app:flow_verticalBias="0"
    app:flow_wrapMode="chain"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_goneMarginEnd="20dp" />


   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In this case it works, but how to make it work if the text views are added dynamically ?

Comment: you have to use the width as match_parent or wrap_content as per your need. See [this](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/java/how+to+set+view+width+programmatically+in+android)

Answer (score 1):

Just set the width **match_parent** of textView @+id/text6

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="[FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFaslkfjadflskjflasdkjfsdlajkfasdlfjkasdlfjkaslkdfjasdflkjasdfasdlfjksdafFFFFsdflkfdaslkfjsdafkljsdlafkjdasfljk]"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
```

Answer (score 1):

i Have similar issue i just set to match parent and margin working fine code snippet

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_20sdp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_22sdp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/font_muli"
    android:text="@string/welcome_msg"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_11sdp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_login"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btn_login"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btn_login" />
```

Where btn_login is MaterialButton.